# ssl redirect not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I've just set up my domain to use ssl and have added this code to a .htaccess file (at root):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)*mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R]
```

it redirects all traffic from mysite.com but traffic from WWW.mysite.com comes up as untrusted. 
I've tried adding www before mysite.com:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)*www.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R]
```

but it didn't work. Can someone that understands this code please help..

UPDATE: https://mysite.com/ works ok, but mysite.com (without https://) attempts to redirect to https://www.mysite.com/ and comes up with and "untrusted certificate message, this certificate is only valid for mysite.com/" 
(obvious?) NOTE: mysite.com isn't actually my web site, I've substituted it for my websites name as I can't disclose the address of my own site yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to redirect all hits to go to https://mysite.com/ and not to https://www.mysite.com/.

If that is the case, than you have a problem in your last rewrite rule - edit it to be

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com/$1 [R]
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will redirect all traffic to your site from HTTP to HTTPS

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Thanks, I also worked out that I needed to change this line:

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R] to
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com/$1 [R] as my ssl certificate is for mysite.com not www.mysite.com.

Are these methods seo friendly? I'd hate for my website to not be indexed by google because of the redirects..

Comment: This tool [SEO Redirect Checker](http://www.webconfs.com/redirect-check.php) will supposedly answer your question.